# Объединить метки [репозиторий] и [repository]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [репозиторий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9) и [repository](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repository), так как они  являются тем же самым только на разных языках. В качестве основной предлагаю сделать русскоязычную метку.

---

*Дополнительна информация о метках:*

- метка [репозиторий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9) - 40 вопросов, есть краткое описание метки;
- метка [repository](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repository) - 62 вопроса, есть краткое описание метки.

Comment: Метки, на самом деле, кривые.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repository+git 1/6 вопросов по гиту.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9+-git половина вопросов по гиту.

Нужно для начала либо описание поменять, сделать как на том же SOen, либо разделить метки и добавить, к примеру,[tag:гит-репозиторий].

Comment: А воз и ныне. У нас по прежнему две эти метки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вопрос особо сообщество не заинтересовал пока, видно время не пришло.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нужны две разные метки:

- git-репозиторий
- паттерн-репозиторий, шаблон-репозиторий

Плюсы данного варианта:

- При подборе меток сам участник выберет более подходящую. Это плюс - визуально наглядно, что ты имеешь ввиду: все эти краткие описания меток мало кто будет читать и следовать текстовым рекомендациям по добавлению дополнительх меток.

Минусы данного варианта:

- Да, разумеется придётся проделать первоначальную работу по переделке меток на существующих вопросах (62 с меткой repository, 40 с меткой репозиторий - всего около сотни). Это минус, но возможно не такой и большой.

---

PS Если вы согласны с данным подходом (две различные метки), но считаете, что есть более подходящие варианты наименования - проголосуте "за" вариант и добавьте свою версию в комментариях или прямо в ответе-голосовалке.

Comment: Почему не pattern-репозиторий или шаблон-репозиторий, или template-репозиторий?

Comment: @Suvitruf Потому что вы прямо в режиме онлайн наблюдаете за созданием опроса :)

Comment: лучше всё таки писать _шаблон-репозиторий_, если мы последовательно придерживаемся русского языка

Answer (score 1):

Метки объединить нужно и как обычно основной меткой должна быть метка на русском языке.

Термин репозиторий является многозначным, поэтому необходимо исправить описание, указав на неоднозначность понятия (это хорошо пояснено в [кратком описании метки](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/repository/info) на enso) и добавив рекомендацию участникам добавлять метки, устраняющие неоднозначность (либо git, либо паттерны проектирования/архитектура)

Плюсы данного варианта:

- Простота и наглядность
- Унификация с en so

Минусы данного варианта:

- Вероятно, большинство участников не будет читать краткое описание при выборе вопроса и следовать рекомендациям по устранению неоднозначности. В момент написания вопроса не до этого и работу по корректировке меток будут делать другие участники, в том числе и увеличивая нагрузку на очередь проверок.

Comment: Еще один минус - фильтрация вопросов по меткам, некто хочет прочитать про паттерн репозиторий например, а у него половина результатов о системах контроля версий

Comment: @yolosora Это можно смягчить, добавив различающиеся метки в запрос (и реальный минус - это нагрузка на проверяющих, кто будет корректировать неоднозначность). Но в принципе, можете добавить в текст - я сделал ответ общим.